# Calculate stack layout with Ida Python

Tags: ida, idapython, arm, stack-variables, idc

In Arm in the beginning of function

```
push r4-r6,lr
sub sp sp 0x4
```

In the end of function

```
pop r4-r6,pc
add sp sp 0x4
```

That mean sp is decreased by 4 register*4 bytes+4 bytes for local variables , related to caller function

How do calculate it with Ida Python? I mean calc the offset of stack between 2 function

`idc.get_func_attr(ea, idc.FUNCATTR_FRSIZE)` retudn only the size of local var, that didn't calculate the size of registers that push to stack

Comment: `idc.get_func_attr(ea, idc.FUNCATTR_FRSIZE)`

Comment: @R4444 that only the size of local var, that didn't calculate the size of registers that push to stack